Attempting to use locally cloned version of Python package in Docker throws metadata error
I am testing an experimental library version and must run it in a docker container locally rather than as a pip install.
As a result, I copy all of the files from the locally cloned library into the working directory of Docker and do relative imports.
My file structure is the following:
PYOPENSKY-AWS/
├── pyopensky/
│   ├── .github/
│   ├── .pytest_cache/
│   ├── docs/
│   ├── scripts/
│   ├── src/pyopensky/
│   │   ├── init.py
│   │   ├── api.py
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   ├── impala.py
│   │   ├── py.typed
│   │   ├── rest.py
│   │   ├── s3.py
│   │   ├── schema.py
│   │   ├── time.py
│   │   └── trino.py
│   └── tests/
│       ├── .gitignore
│       ├── license.txt
│       ├── poetry.lock
│       ├── pyproject.toml
│       └── readme.md
├── Dockerfile
├── lambda.py

From here I use a docker file to import the files:
# Use the official Python base image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10

# Set the working directory to the root of the Lambda function directory
WORKDIR /var/task

# Copy the application files
COPY pyopensky/src/pyopensky /var/task/pyopensky
COPY lambda.py .

# Command to run the Lambda function handler
CMD ["lambda.getHistoricalADSB"]

And a Lambda.py function:
import json
import datetime
from pyopensky.trino import Trino

def getHistoricalADSB(event, context):
    print("Running")
    try:
        # Initialize Trino
        trino = Trino()
        # Rest of code is unimportant

The issue is that when I build this docker file:
docker build -t get-historical-adsb .  
docker run -p 9000:8080 get-historical-adsb

And then call it (with an empty body {}):
http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations

It throws the error:

Unable to import module 'lambda': No package metadata was found for pyopenskyntimes-update.html

The error occurs at the import statement:
from pyopensky.trino import Trino

It appears that the lambda.py is unable to find the pyopensky library despite it being cloned directly into the same folder as the lambda.py. How can I fix this?

Wouldn't you need an __init__.py file in src/pyopensky/ in order to import it?
